# Manipulating TimeWithZone in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have this rails application that needs to capture a time date and a time zone in one of the forms, for example:
Time zone: 'Hong Kong' as string
Date time: '31/12/2013 23:59' as string

The default time zone for the application is set to 'Melbourne', the application currently accept the date time and automatically convert to '2013-12-31 23:59:00 +1100', which +1100 is the Melbourne time zone offset with daylight saving.

I want the application to:
1) Take '31/12/2013 23:59:00' as a time of the selected time zone, i.e. Hong Kong
2) Convert the Hong Kong time to Melbourne time, i.e. '31/12/2013 23:59:00 +0800' to '01/01/2014 02:59 +1100' and persist into the database.
3) During the conversion in 2), daylight saving will need to be taken care of.

I have written up the following code would do exactly what i want it to do ONLY works in the controller. However, it doesn't work when I move it to the model with before_create filter

```
time_zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(params[:time_zone])
date_time = DateTime.strptime(params[:date_time], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')

new_date_time = date_time.change(offset: time_zone.formatted_offset(false))
melbourne_date_time = new_date_time.in_time_zone(Time.zone)
```

The reason it doesn't work in the model is that in the controller, I manually parse the date time string to a date time object. But in the model, rails automatically convert the date time string into a TimeWithZone object... therefore, can't really alter the object...

I have done fair a bit of googling and still can't work out the exact solution.

Any help will be appreciated!

P.S. The application is on Rails 3.2.12. I am planning to run the conversion within a method attached with the before_create filter of a model.

Cheers

Comment: What does your model look like? What happens when you use it? You won't be able to access the controller's `params` directly from the model.

Comment: Ari, i understand i won't be able to access the params from the model. The code above is a direct copy from my spike solution i did in the controller. In the model, time_zone and date_time are attributes to my model, i didn't have to retrieve it from params. The problem I am having is to manipulate the TimeWithZone object. I need to force the timezone of the TimwWithZone (date_time) to a timezone of the user's selection, then use the in_time_zone method to convert to Melbourne time.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set default `time_zone` for your rails application.

- Open up `config/application.rb`
- set default time_zone by using this

  ```
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.time_zone = 'Hong Kong'
    config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Hong Kong'

  end
  ```

Comment: Hi Gopal, as stated in my question the default time_zone for the application is 'Melbourne' (config.time_zone = 'Melbourne' in config/application.rb). The user can select any timezone available at 'time_zone_select' on the form for my problem, i.e. Hong Kong, Adelaide, etc.

Comment: I am happy with 'Melbourne' as my default time zone.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a (dirty?) way to archive what I want in the model.

User input from the form: 
Time Zone - 'Hong Kong' as String,
Date Time - '31/12/2013 23:59:00' as String

```
config.time_zone = 'Melbourne'# in config/application.rb

self.time_zone # 'Hong Kong' as String
self.date_time # '31/12/2013 23:59:00 +1100' as TimeWithZone

class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :populate_date_time_with_zone
  def populate_date_time_with_zone
    original_tz = Time.zone # Capture the system default timezone, 'Melbourne'
    Time.zone = self.time_zone # Change the timezone setting for this thread to 'Hong Kong'
    dt = Time.zone.parse(self.date_time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %I:%M%p')) #Dirty??
    self.date_time = dt.in_time_zone(original_tz) # '01/01/2014 02:59:00 +1100' as TimeWith Zone
  end
end
```

Is there a better way of doing it than printing the date time into a string than parse it again with an altered Time.zone?